# How to execute.cql file from cqlsh? Where should the.cql file be placed to execute or run in cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have created a `.cql` file to create a table. It's in my local location in the C drive. When I try to execute the source command in cqlsh, I'm unable to execute the file.

How should I execute the source command and where to place the `.cql` file to be executed? Why do I get this type of an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **-f** option to give a file location to cqlsh. You just need to make sure that the location is accessible for the Cassandra user.

Here in the example, I created a *test.cql* file in /tmp/ folder. I was able to execute the cql file using this command.

```
cqlsh -f /tmp/test.cql
```